# How can I avoid API call when clicked back button of the browser in Angular 6?

Tags: angular6

For Example:

"I am navigating from page A to page B.On page B I clicked the back button of the browser which should land me back to page A but I need to avoid API calls for page A through clicking the back button of the browser."

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to "API calls that are sent as a result of loading the JavaScript for page A", then you will want to utilize [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the information in the browser across page loads. To implement this, you will have to provide logic that checks `localStorage` for the "cached" information before calling an API for the data. That way, if your user hits the back button on the browser, the JavaScript will check that there is already data from the API in `localStorage` and then skip making the API call.

Note: you will need to `localStorage.clear()` or `localStorage.removeItem('itemKey')` to remove the item if you want to clear the "cached" data. This logic will depend on your use case.

An example could be as follows:

```js
@Component({
  selector:    'app-hero-list',
  templateUrl: './hero-list.component.html'
})
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!window.localStorage.getItem('myData')) {
      this.heroService.loadData().subscribe(
        (data) => window.localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(data))
      );
    } else {
      // Load the data by parsing the stored JSON string:
      // const data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('myData'))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But local storage would only save the data in the form of String I guess!!.In my case it is an array

Comment: This is true. This can be combined with [`JSON.stringify(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert your data to and from strings (and back into JS objects). (Added to answer)

Answer (score 1):

Is your page a & page b part of the same angular site ? If so then you can store your array as global object in the service layer. When you go back to page b, just access the value and if not null then do not make service calls. Another option is to use local storage as described above